# Single postgres transaction locks xmin for the whole cluster

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking, select-for-update

One of my applications performs a lock with a following request

```
SELECT … FROM locks WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
```

This query lasts as long as application lifetime. Table itself contains only one column with a single row `id = 1`. I know it's not the best approach to acquire locks and I expect `xmin` for that database to stuck with this `SELECT … FOR UPDATE …` xid.

But in fact I'm getting situation where all transactions in my cluster, even in **another databases** are stuck with that xmin, including autovacuum process.

At first I was thinking that streaming replication with enabled `hot_standby_feedback` may be involved somehow, but it's continues to happen even with replication turned off at all.

Server version is 11.3.
There is no long running prepared transactions in pg_prepared_xacts or any replication running. Xmin blocks cluster-wide exactly on `SELECT FOR UPDATE` xid.

Comment: I too would expect it to be per database.  And that is what I find.  How are you determining this?  11.3 is well behind the times, the current is 11.16.  That is like 3.5 years of known unfixed bugs you are burdened with.

Comment: Just reproduced on 14.4.

Comment: Again, how are you determining this?  What query or log message or experiment are you running to know that this is happening?